# Trilateration to know relative distance to a point.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I've been trying to find the distance $d$ in this system where I only can know the distances $a0, a1, b0, b1, c0, c1$ but not the position of $A, B, C, P0, P1$.
I tried 2D trilateration using nonlinear least squares method but I'm not being able to solve it.

[image]

Is it possible to solve it? If it is, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the only restriction you have is that the distance $d$ you are looking for has to be the third side of triangles with sides $a_0,a_1,d$; $b_0,b_1,d$; $c_0,c_1,d$.

But these constraints mean that $|a_0-a_1|\leq d\leq a_0+a_1$ and equivalent for $b$ and $c$. So you can only restrict $d$ to an interval, and with $d$ in that interval, you will be able to construct triangles (possibly degenerate) on a base of length $d$ which satisfy the constraints.

Comment: I see your point, thanks! I cant upvote you because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in other words, this system has 10 degrees of freedom (the 2 coordinates of each point) and 9 known terms (6 distances + 3 arbitrary coordinates needed to fix the system on the plane), therefore it is underdetermined, you need one more known term (provided that there are no redundant data) to obtain the distance *d* univocally.